# Eclipse CTD macro syntax error

Tags: c, eclipse, macros, stringification

I am using the following macro successfully.

```
#define SECTION(a)  __attribute__ ((section(#a)))
```

Now in the same file I defined a new macro, and I tried using it in my code:

```
#define GP_RAM_DATA_1       SECTION(".gp_ram1.data")

GP_RAM_DATA_1 int foo = 5;
```

The code compiles and runs fine, without compiler warnings or errors, however Eclipse marks the line I use the macro yellow, with a note for syntax error.

Is there anything wrong with my code? Is it an Eclipse bug, or should I change anything?

Comment: Using `gcc` on linux, the posted lines compiled/linked with no warnings nor errors  This is with `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -std=gnu99 -pedantic` for the `gcc` compile parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an Eclipse bug. If the compiler is happy (and you do not disable warnings), all is good.